# ddply - spaces in variable name contained in an object

Tags: r, plyr, reshape2

Is there a way to pass both named variables and an object containing a variable name with spaces into ddply? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
> library(plyr)
> dat <- data.frame(id1=rep(c("A","B"),8),id2=rep(c("C","D","E","F"),4),x=rnorm(16))
> vname <- "id2"
#works without spaces
> ddply(dat,c("id1",vname),colwise(sum))
  id1 id2          x
1   A   C -1.1215505
2   A   E -1.4507586
3   B   D  1.5064013
4   B   F -0.5428153
> vname <- "id 2"
> names(dat)[2] <- vname
#breaks with spaces
> ddply(dat,c("id1",vname),colwise(sum))
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:4: unexpected numeric constant
1: id 2
      ^
#backticks work when manually entering the name
> ddply(dat,c("id1","`id 2`"),colwise(sum))
  id1 id 2          x
1   A    C -1.1215505
2   A    E -1.4507586
3   B    D  1.5064013
4   B    F -0.5428153
#backticks don't work when pointing to object containing name
> ddply(dat,c("id1",`vname`),colwise(sum))
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:4: unexpected numeric constant
1: id 2
      ^
```

Comment: It will much easier to just not do that, and instead use properly formatted column names.

Comment: agreed, but that would be actually be cumbersome in this particular instance. i can find work-arounds by adjusting names temporarily, but I would prefer not to have a bunch of conditional statements to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this , but it looks UGLY:

```
 ddply(dat,c("id1",paste("`",vname,"`",sep='')),colwise(sum))
  id1 id 2          x
1   A    C  1.3719443
2   A    E -0.3264330
3   B    D -0.3231757
4   B    F -0.6807928
```

as said in the comment USE properly formatted name.

Comment: ugly it is, but not as ugly as the alternative in this exact context. thanks!

Comment: @user2167315 I am really curious, what is the context that don't let you rename your column? ( and when I say ugly, I am joking so hop no offense).

Comment: they can be renamed, but it would just be annoying to do so. it's for an interactive reporting interface that needs nice looking titles/labels/etc... so the variables either need to be named that way by the end. since there a lot of different combinations of variables/graphs/tables changing the names would require a long series of conditional statements to how to change them and when.

Comment: @user2167315 generally the name of variable if not you display. Imagine you need to write your report in another language? or to change the variable name by sector/user...Whatever I think you get my point..

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect non-syntatic names to work nicely with all functions and packages.

They will, however, work with `data.table`,

Use `data.table` instead. The equivalent of `colwise(fun)` is `lapply(.SD, fun)`

```
  dat <- data.frame(id1=rep(c("A","B"),8),
          "id 2"=rep(c("C","D","E","F"),4),x=rnorm(16), check.names= FALSE)

  library(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(dat)
  vname <- "id 2"
  DT[,lapply(.SD, sum) , by = c('id1',vname)]
```

If you wanted to stick with `plyr`

then

```
as.character(as.name(vname))
```

will create the character vector

You could create a function that did this

```
charN <- function(x) as.character(as.name(x))
```